# Semantic zoom with grouped items for the zoomed-out view in a Javascript Metro application

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm adding semantic zoom to my application and I'm having issues with the data binding in the zoomed out listview.
In the normal (zoomed in) listview I'm binding grouped data and it renders fine. 
For the zoomed out listview I would like to render the same grouped data (same itemDataSource and groupDataSource) , but with different itemTemplate and groupTemplate (the same as the normal view but smaller).

The problem I'm having is that when I zoom out I get an error at ui.js line 2117 saying "0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Object.defineProperty: argument is not an Object".

I've tryed binding the zoomed out listview itemDataSource property to the groups.dataSource collection and not set the groupDataSource property (like all the examples I found on the web) and I works fine.

Why is the zoomed out view not rendering grouped items like the normal view?

**EDIT:**
Seems like the zoomed out view behaves in a different way than the normal (zoomed in) listview. While the zoomed in view accepts both itemDataSource and groupDataSource, the zoomed out view only accepts itemDataSource.
I edited the [Microsoft Official Semantic Zoom Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-grouping-and-6d032cc1) (scenario2.html) and changed the zoomedOutListView to use myGroupedList.dataSource as itemDataSource and the same issue arises.

Code before:

```
        <div id="zoomedOutListView"
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-options="{ 
                itemDataSource: myGroupedList.groups.dataSource, 
                itemTemplate: semanticZoomTemplate, 
                selectionMode: 'none', 
                tapBehavior: 'invoke', 
                swipeBehavior: 'none' 
            }"
        ></div>
```

Code after (which reproduces the issue):

```
            <div id="zoomedOutListView"
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
            data-win-options="{ 
                itemDataSource: myGroupedList.dataSource, //originally was myGroupedList.groups.dataSource
                itemTemplate: semanticZoomTemplate, 
                selectionMode: 'none', 
                tapBehavior: 'invoke', 
                swipeBehavior: 'none' 
            }"
        ></div>
```

Thanks.
Diego

Comment: I know this is old but did you ever find a solution to this problem? Having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom IListDataSource, make sure that you implement itemFromKey method.

Comment: Thanks. No, I'm not using a custom IListDataSource. I'm using the default WinJS.Binding.List and the dataSource property it comes with.

Comment: Are you sure you are assigning the result of list.createGrouped as the datasource of the ListView?

Comment: Hi Yasser. Yes, I'm using the result of listGrouped. I edited the question with more information about the issue, more specifically editing the official semantic zoom sample to reproduce it. Thanks.